# Sudo apt update issue

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, updates

I am trying to update sudo apt, with the simple command. But I am completely new to ubuntu, and I receive the following error:

```
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Get:13 https://packages.stripe.dev/stripe-cli-debian-local stable InRelease [4.276 B]
Get:14 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done    
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can someone suggest what should I do to fix it?

Comment: remove the ppa's that error out or adjust the line to a correct one. See"setting"  in  "software update" in the menu.

Comment: A quick look at using my browser (*copy link from your paste & right-click to open in new tab*) & details on screen & it shows you trying to use a PPA or 3rd party *personal package archive* which doesn't support your release.  PPAs are 3rd party so all security checks as to content, safe or not, good for your system are on you to perform - did you perform any?  It doesn't provide support for *jammy* or 22.04 should have told you before adding it wasn't going to be good.

Comment: A look at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily (*pre-adding usually*) to ensure it's safe, trustworthy etc. should have told you it hasn't seen attention since 2019; however you Ubuntu 22.04 LTS release is the 2022-April release which is newer; thus unless your purpose is to explore problems using *abandoned* software it'll have nothing safe for you...  Clicking on the "*filter*" (published in drop down) won't list your *jammy* release etc. support up to 19.04 (*disco*) last!    Fix is to remove it & check before adding next time when dealing with PPAs